# Calling a single view in different UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have declared a `UIView` inside a `UIViewController` class. Can I call this `UIView` in another `UIViewController` class?

If its possible how can I call it?

Comment: does it need to be the same object or can it be just different objects from the same class?

Comment: different objects in another view controller class

Comment: make this UIView as a property of your UIViewController, than call it as viewController.yourView;

Comment: Hi demon9733, can u be more specific. am new to this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a single instance of a view in a number of views/viewControllers. Typically I do the same with Views that carry advertisements.

You pass them along as you would do with any other object. 
If you do not create it in Interface Bulder (I suggest creating it programmatically) then you may want to define it within your application delegate rather than a view controller and pass it to the individual view controllers that make use of it.

Within the view controller just add it as sub view accordingly, as you would do it with any other view too.

There is one thing though. When you add this view to another super view for the second time or more then it will be removed from its prior super view. That means that you will have to add it as super view again, when its prior super view becomes visible again. A view can only be part of one view hierarchy at a time.

---

Sample code, thanks to Gordon:

```
/* Untested and simplified */
AppDelegate.h:
@property ( strong, nonatomic) ReuseableView reuseableView
```

;

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize reuseableView; 

/* in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ...*/ 
reuseableView = [[alloc] init]; // or init from nib, initwithframe, etc.
```

viewController.m

```
/* In each view controller that uses the view */
 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
  [self.view addSubview:((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).reuseableView]; 
}

 - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
  [((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).ReuseableView removeFromSuperview];
```

}

---

I am not quite sure whether this `removeFromSuperview` is really required. The next `addSubview` will remove it from its existing superview anyway and if `addSubview` is called on the same super view twice in a row then it does not do any harm. However, it is save using `removeFromSuperview` at this point.

Well, summarized that is basically it. You define, create and store your shared view (the reusableView in Gordon's example) at a common place. The application delegate is a good place for that. In each view's controller that uses the shared view you fetch it from the delegate and add it as subview to the current view.

Comment: Hi Hermann,thanks fr ur rply. can u explain me with  sample code pls

Comment: Nothing worked out. i have created saveTaskView as a uiview in MMViewController class and i want to access that saveTaskView in my another class say in my case 'keyContacts'. This puts me in lot of pressure.pls help

Comment: /* Untested and simplified */
AppDelegate.h
'@property ( strong, nonatomic) ReuseableView* reuseableView;
AppDelegate.m
@synthesize reuseableView;
/* in did finish launching with ...*/
    reuseableView = [[alloc] init]; // or init from nib, initwithframe, etc.
/* In each view that uses the view, 
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view addSubview:((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).reuseableView];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).ReuseableView removeFromSuperview];
}
'

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting, I'm not used to the comment entry system.

Comment: Thank u so much. i will try this and let u know

Comment: Hi Gordon i get an error as Unknown type name 'ReuseableView'

Comment: Roxana, what exactly is the error and where exactly do you get it? Unfortunately I do not have a code example available here at this workplace. I will take Gordon's sample and include it well formatted in my answer. Assume that Gordon does not mind.

Comment: Hermann:I have a uivew declared as saveTaskView in my MMViewController class. I want to use the same saveTaskView in my another class called keyContacts.I have used this code to access it:MMViewController *mm = [[MMViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeetingMakerDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
  [mm.view addSubview:saveTaskView]; 
this throws me an error that says cannot load nib file named saveTaskView

Comment: Hermann:Cant get u. this coding is already been done by another developer who has left recently.

Comment: Sorry, at first I did not see the actual code on your comment. Well, again, I'd suggest declaring and storing the shared view in your application Delegate. However, does your saveTaskView have a nib file at all? How did you create the saveTaskView? There must be some alloc/init to create the view.

Comment: yes it has a nib file.the thing is am able to access this view in MMViewController class using [self.view addSubview:saveTaskView];  and it works fine

Comment: And now you receive an error indicating that the nib file cannot be loaded? That root cause must be somewhere else. And yes, of course you can access a property of a view controller from within the view controller. But now you are asking how to access this property from multiple view controllers. Gordon and I made a suggestion how this can be done. There are other ways of doing that but I am confident that the suggested one is appropriate.

Comment: All right. Our suggestion so far is a) 'legal' and b) quite pragmatic. It would not force you to make a lot of changes to your existing code. Just move the property and alloc/init from one class to another and use ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).xxx to access it from everywhere you want. Next time, when you start such a thing from scratch, you may want to consider using a singleton pattern for shared view. Both work fine but I think that using a singleton is more "out of the book".

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass UIView and import it on the ViewControllers where I wanna use it

```
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourView" owner:self options:nil];
    yourView = (YourView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you set its frame and `[self.view addSubview:yourView]`

Comment: Hi Lucas, it throws me a debug error when i do like that. it says cannot load nib file

Comment: Hi Lucas, where do i need to put this code?(sorry if it sounds silly)

Comment: You could, for example, write this on your viewControllers' viewWillAppear:

Comment: Lucas: ok thanx. will give it a try

Comment: Lucas: It throws me an error saying Missing '[' at start of message send expression